# Need uploaded file path to convert to Byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

The path value returns a root website path.  However, I don't want to store images there, I want to get the image from the user (when they upload from local).

I can hard code the string with my local path and it will work but that wont work in other environments.  I am running .net core 1.0.

Controller:

```
foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    string path = Path.GetFullPath(model.Filename);

                    var img = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(path, file.FileName));
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        model.FileData = ms.ToArray();
                    }

                }
            }
```

View:

```
<input asp-for="Filename" type="text" id="upload-banner" class="form-control" placeholder="Upload Image" readonly>
<span class="input-group-btn">
<input  id="i_file" type="file" name="files" multiple />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-primary">Upload</button>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused how file uploading works.  The back end code does not have any access to the filesystem that is providing the file; instead, it comes over the HTTP pipeline.  The back end code must accept the file and save it somewhere locally before you can work with it on the local file system.

Code like this might work:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file) 
{
    if (file.ContentLength > 0) 
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

[See this link](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/) for a complete example.

Comment: Thank you,  sorry i did not explain myself correctly, English is not my native language. after reviewing this,  i got it to work , problem is that net core has changed a lot of mvc elements. thanks for responding.